# Custom Separator Image disappears in UItableviewcell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am loading custom separator image in uitableview cell.

Here is my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *CellID=@"Cell"
   MyTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:SwitchCellIdentifier];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    UIImageview *aSwitch = [[UIImageview alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"divider.png"]];
    separator.frame = CGRectMake(0,50,320,1);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:seperator];

}

if(cell.height == 22)
{
   /// here i am setting frame for uiimageview
}
```

but i am getting seperator image disappears for only one row out of 20 while scrolling.

Can you please help why it is loading like this.

Comment: The code allocates UIImageview *aSwitch, then refers to separator.  Is this a cut and paste problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you've put your separator `UIImage` out of the bounds of the cell, and set `cell.clipsToBounds = NO;` to have the separator image displayed, the separator image might get hidden by drawing the next cell.

You can't control the z-index of the cells as they're being drawn on screen, it depends from where you're scrolling (bottom to top, or top to bottom).

If that's indeed you're issue, you can either put the divider inside the cell's frame, or if your separator is thin enough use:

```
[TableView setSeparatorColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:...]]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.tblView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,370) //set as u need
style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.tblView.delegate=self;
self.tblView.dataSource=self;
[self.view addSubview:self.tblView];

UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 10)];//set as u ne
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"divider.png"]];
[self.tblView setTableHeaderView:v];
[self.tblView setTableFooterView:v];
[v release];
```